# submit select value from template to django form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a Group model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
   leader = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
   description = models.TextField()
   joined = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

and a form to update the said group:

```
class UpdateGroup(UpdateView):
    model = Group
    form_class = UpdateGroupForm
    template_name = 'update_group.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        group = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user_detail', args=[str(group.pk)]))
```

I want the `leader` of the Group to have the ability to give over their leadership to another member who has `joined`. In my UpdateUser template I have two buttons:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" name="update">UPDATE</button>
    <select>
    {% for member in group.joined.all %}
        {% if member != group.leader%}
            <option value={{ member }}>{{ member }}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="change_leader">CHANGE LEADER</button>
</form>
```

The frontend works here and it renders how I want, the only issue now is how do I submit an update to the Group with the`UPDATE` button and just the `leader` of the group with the `CHANGE LEADER` button?

Do I need two different forms? I would like the `CHANGE LEADER` button to update the form and return to the GroupDetail view, but only if that button is clicked. Meaning, if by mistake the leader clicked one of the `<option value={{ member }}>{{ member }}</option>` but hit `UPDATE` instead of `CHANGE LEADER`, the leader of the Group wouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going about it a different way completely. Added a new view, form, and url for changing the leader of a Group. Then in the `change_leader.html` template I did this:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <select id="newLeaderSelect">
    {% for member in group.joined.all %}
        {% if member != group.leader%}
            <option id='newLeader' value={{ member.id }}>{{ member }}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button>CHANGE LEADER</button>
    {{form.errors}}
</form>

<script>
    let leader = document.getElementById('leader')
    let newLeaderSelect = document.getElementById('newLeaderSelect')
    leader.value = newLeaderSelect.value
    
    newLeaderSelect.onchange = () => {
        leader.value = newLeaderSelect.value
    }
</script>
```

This worked fine, but if anyone knows how to go about having both on the same form feel free to post an answer.